# How to retrieve eventId from the provided json data

Tags: c#, json, interface

Help me out to retrieve eventID from this json data:

```
{"events":[{"eventId":1579,"eventName":"NN - Marathon Rotterdam","startDateTime":"2018-04-06 09:00:00","endDateTime":"2018-04-08 16:30:00"}],"autostartEvent":null}
```

property were set on interfaces

```
public interface IEventList : IList<IEvent>
{

    DateTime StartDate { get; }

    DateTime EndDate { get; }

    IEvent AutoStartEvent { get; }
}


public interface IEvent
{
    int Id { get; }

    string Name { get; }

    DateTime StartDate { get; }

    DateTime EndDate { get; }
```

}

that interface was initialize on eventlist class where deserialize object were mapped on events property.

```
 public class EventList : IEventList
{
    public object  Events { get; set; }
```

}

```
 try
        {
             var deserializeData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            return new EventList
                  {
                     Events=deserializeData 
                  };
        }
```

so i want to retrieve the eventid from events object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one approach is that,

Directly parse your JSON with `JObject` provided by newtonsoft and then retrieve your `eventId` by [Querying](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJson.htm) your JSON,

So this way you don't need to manage the class hierarchy anymore,

```
string json = "Your json here";

JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

int eventId = (int)jObject["events"][0]["eventId"];
```

**Output:** (From Debugger)

[image]

**Note:** You need to install [NewtonSoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) NuGet package and import `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` namespace to your program.

Answer (score 2):

Create related classes on bottom;

```
public class Event
{
    public int eventId { get; set; }
    public string eventName { get; set; }
    public string startDateTime { get; set; }
    public string endDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Event> events { get; set; }
    public object autostartEvent { get; set; }
}
```

And Deserialize the json like that;

```
RootObject root = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
                      .Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonText);

int exampleEventId = root.events.FirstOrDefault().eventId;//Example
```